# How to get user lock / screensaver delay?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, screensaver

How do I get the user's setting for screensaver / machine lock time?

Is there a function in C#?
If not, what is the WIN API function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen saver timeout is obtained by calling [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) with the action `SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 0):

Registry key - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop look at the value of ScreenSaveTimeOut

Keep in mind your application will have to run with elevated rights in order to access the registry.

Comment: The key you provided does not exsit on my machine. Did you mean `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut`,

Comment: This is exactly why you should not poke in the registry for this.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut` is where the values are saved when you save them from the Settings UI, and the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop` is where values created by group policies are saved. And the SystemParametersInfoW (or SystemParametersInfoA) gives the value which is in effect, no matter how it has been defined.